# How to customize seasonal pricing in Sitecore Commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am aware on how to set a seasonal price for a product. 
Our site sells online tickets. The price of a ticket by default is 75 USD.
But during December it is 100 USD. So, I configure the date and price. When user browses the site in December, it will show as 100.

The new requirement is as follows.
Say, this is August. User wants to purchase the ticket for a December event. The price should be 100.

This is not possible out of box.
Though I have set the future price for the product, when user adds it to cart (in august) and proceeds to checkout, the unit price shown is 75. Because it is getting the price for the current timestamp.

The tickets are for a theme park that sell everyday and are of 2 variants - Adult & Child.

Could anyone please guide me, what pipelines should be extended to achieve our goal.

Using Sitecore commerce 8.2.1 u3 with sc 8.2 u5

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same product.

Your ticket, is a product *within a timeframe*. Just like an off-peak hotel room, valid only between October and April, as an example.

Now I don't know your full setup, but sounds to me like you need to create something similar. "Off Season Ticket" and "Ticket" (or whatever makes sense in your case).

Changing the price of a "Ticket" on certain dates is functionality used to cater for sales events such as Black Friday and so - where specific products are marked down for sale - to clear inventory to make way for next seasons product offerings. Not directly applicable to your case.

To clarify; conditional promotions are applicable to *time of sale*.

There's going to be a *lot* of custom handling you'll need to get done, to get Sitecore Commerce which is almost exclusively aimed at Retail B2C at this time, to work as expected in a case such as yours. For now, however, you need to start looking at your dynamically priced product differently.

Comment: They are theme park tickets with 2 variants-adult & child that are sold everyday. So, in our case, the products/variants should be the same and it's not ideal to have a new variant like adult-offseason as such.

Comment: The alternatives are going to be even less ideal. You will need to customise the pricing engine then.